# In C++ what is the difference between (int *) and &?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, memory-management

I am new to programming and just tinkering on my own to get a better feel for concepts covered in book lessons; however, I cannot find an explanation for the following: In the code below, why are the addresses returned using (INT *), different from those using & ?

```
  char animal[20] = "doberman";
  const char * cat = "tiger";

  std::cout << "\nanimal: " << animal << std::endl;
  std::cout<< "cat: " << cat << std::endl;
  std::cout << "-----\n";
  std::cout << "&animal: " << &animal << std::endl;
  std::cout << "&cat: " << &cat << std::endl;
  std::cout << "(int *) cat: " << (int *) cat << std::endl;
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Pointers

Comment: Because `&` and `(int *)` are not the same thing; turn the question around: why would you expect them to give the *same* result?

Comment: Using `(int *)` is not magically turning your variable into an address ...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The way I understood, they were different ways of achieving the same result. They both would display the location to which the pointer points. I must have misunderstood the lesson.

Comment: @Joshua No, `&cat` gives you the address of the pointer, not the thing it points to.

Comment: @Joce and other duplicate voters, that is definitely not a duplicate. Please pay some attention.

Comment: @Joce How are references relevant here? I may have missed it, in which case I would remove my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `&` means 'address of'.

Using `(int *)` means 'treat value as an address'.

So in this case, the `(int *)` treats the value "tiger" as an `int` pointer. *(sort of)

*It is a little more complicated.  It's not exactly the value `"tiger"`, since it is casting from a `const char *` rather than the string literal itself.  Instead, `cat` is a pointer to where `"tiger"` is in memory, and so `(int *)cat` will actually be an integer pointer to where `cat` is in memory.

On the other hand, `&cat` is the address of `cat` - which is actually the address of the pointer to `"tiger"`.

Comment: So where is the cast of a string literal? All I see is a cast from a `const char*`.

Comment: Good point - I updated my response.  I was a bit hasty on that I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

The code you are showing is illegal (non portable C++).

The syntax `(int *)` means that the address of the string literal `"tiger"` is casted to a pointer to an integer but this is not allowed and it may result in undefined behavior.

You are allowed to cast any pointer type to a pointer to a char or to a pointer to unsigned char, but not the other way around.

The reason is that there are architectures in which integers and other large types MUST be at certain address (e.g. at an address that is a multiple of 4). Just creating the pointer with an invalid address is enough for undefined behavior (dereferencing is not necessary because on some CPUs even just loading an invalid address to a register used for indexing integers can raise an hardware trap).

On a PC (x86) the conversion doesn't creates problems (except may be performance problems) and simply means that the compiler will treat the memory containing `"tige"` as if it was an integer. Dereferencing the integer (i.e. printing `*((int *)&cat)`) should give **1701276020** that is

```
116 +           // ASCII code for 't'
105 * 256 +     // ASCII code for 'i'
103 * 65536 +   // ASCII code for 'g'
101 * 16777216  // ASCII code for 'e'
```

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: an invalid pointer cannot be used in ANY way. Dereferencing is not necessary to run into problems.

Comment: Just saw your edit, interesting points (I am from the x86 ghetto).

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: they're today not so common, but for example I've been working in the past with HP risc machines where just loading bad addresses was terminating the program with bus errors.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `&cat`, where `cat` is a pointer, you are getting the memory location where `cat` itself is stored.

When you do `(int*) cat`, you are simply interpreting the contents of `cat` as an `int*`.

It would be highly unexpected if these two were equivalent.